# Update Filtered HTML 'Allowed HTML tags' for current content

Tags: 7

I have a lot of content currently added to my site which is using the Filtered HTML text format.
It seems that the `<p>` tag was not present in the list of allowed tags when the content was first created and was displaying as plain text.

I have updated the list of allowed tags to include `<p>` but my content is still displaying it as plain text. I know I can just edit the content and save it again which will correct the issue but there are thousands of pieces of content of different content types.

How do I rebuild all content without going into each one and updating?

Comment: Filters are applied on render, so you shouldn't need to do anything except clear the cache